# unable to change orientation of emulator in my hp-g62

Tags: android, android-emulator

I simply want to change the orientation of android emulator on my hp G-63 laptop.

I have tried follow suggestion after going through answers provided on SO but below doesn't work for me.please note that my laptop does not have numpad.

```
ctrl+f12
ctrl+f11
ctrl+fn+f11
ctrl+fn+f11
```

is there any other way to do it except this
please help me.

Comment: have you tried numpad 7?

Comment: oh. that hardens it. have you took a look at this link: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping

Comment: Also, are you trying with left ctrl instead of the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it...i was trying to do it with rctrl,
but lctrl+f11 did trick for me...